Getting default values using TypeNameHandling in Newtonsoft JSON
I'm doing a basic serialize / deserialize with $type included to implement the outbox pattern. however I'm getting the default values.
Here's the code serializing :
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(domainEvent, 
new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }

and for de-serializing
var domainEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDomainEvent>(
    serializedDomainEvent,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All});

here's the domain event i'm trying to serialize
public record SubscriptionSet(Subscription subscription) : IDomainEvent

and lastly the subscription class
public class Subscription : AggregateRoot
{
    private readonly List<Alert> _alerts = new();

    public Guid UserId { get; private set; }
    public SubscriptionTier subscriptionTier { get; private set; }
    public SubscriptionPlan subscriptionPlan { get; private set; }
    public DateOnly StartDate { get; private set; }
    public DateOnly EndDate { get; private set; }
    public bool IsVaild { get; private set; }
    public decimal ComulativeTradingVolume24H { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<Alert> Alerts => _alerts.ToList();
}


The serialization part is working properly but i'm messing up the deserialization part.
This is the serialization output :
{"$type":"Domain.Subscriptions.Events.SubscriptionSet, Domain","subscription":{"$type":"Domain.Subscriptions.Subscription, Domain","UserId":"e09cf0c7-5cc7-4fd7-b899-ac9dc74a70a4","subscriptionTier":1,"subscriptionPlan":1,"StartDate":"2024-12-05","EndDate":"2025-03-05","IsVaild":true,"ComulativeTradingVolume24H":0.0,"Alerts":{"$type":"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Domain.Users.Alert, Domain]], System.Private.CoreLib","$values":[]},"Id":"ad35aeb0-c2dc-4ac2-a19f-e7fe9fcbc0c9"}}


Try using public setters

Your setters are all private.  Try making them public or applying [JsonProperty].  See: Private setters in Json.Net.  Also, I'm not sure Alerts will populate since you declared it as an IReadOnlyList<Alert>, you may need to mark it with [JsonIgnore] and apply [JsonProperty("Alerts")] to private readonly List<Alert> _alerts

How do you expect it to call a private setter?

Thanks, that actually worked :) , as someone who doesn't like to decorate props, I implemented  a custom contract resolver to get access to private setters.

As Told by the awesome people in the Comments, Private setters was the problem
public Guid UserId { get; private set; }

in order for this to work, either change setter to public or user [JsonProperty]
[JsonProperty]
public Guid UserId { get; private set; }

or if you don't like to decorate your classes with attributes you can, implement a custom contract resolver
public class PrivateResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member,
          MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop =  base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (!prop.Writable)
        {
            var property = member as PropertyInfo;

            bool hasPrivateSetters = property?.GetSetMethod(true) != null;

            prop.Writable = hasPrivateSetters;
        }

        return prop;
    }
}

and in your de-serialization code do this
var domainEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDomainEvent>(
    outboxMessage.Content,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { 
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All , 
        ContractResolver = new PrivateResolver() });

